# What is the gravitational potential at the centre of the earth?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential

Assuming the gravitational potential at infinity to be zero and ignoring the other celestial bodies, what is the gravitational potential at the centre of Earth?
As no force acts at infinity the gravitational potential is zero. Similarly as no force acts in the centre of the Earth would the gravitational potential be zero too?

Comment: Are we assuming that there aren't any other bodies such as the sun which influence the potential in a nontrivial manner?

Comment: For instance, assuming the Earth alone and a constant density the potential will be $\frac{-5GM}{2R}$, where M and R are mass and radius of earth

Comment: @Cicero Yes, no such bodies are to be taken into account.

Comment: Gravitational potential is zero at infinity  because we have assumed it to be zero there ( that makes our life easier) not because the force is zero there.